# No room for 10 tags in technologies for education

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, jobs

On Careers 2.0, the *Technologies* field for an education has the hint

> A list of up to 10 core technologies you studied.

Problem is, the field is limited to 100 characters. Sadly, it's hard to fit 10 tags into that when one has tags like [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming), [discrete-mathematics](/questions/tagged/discrete-mathematics) and [operating-system](/questions/tagged/operating-system) as being quite relevant to one's studies.

It'd be super if the field size got upped a bit, so one can have 10 tags, even when using large tags like those.

Comment: Is [discrete-mathematics] really a technology? I think they're looking more for things like [Javascript], [Ruby-on-rails] and [C++].

Comment: @RobertHarvey That wouldn't really apply to the computer science I study. It's quite theoretical and focused more on general concepts that specific implementations of them. I could tag it with [tag:sml], but SML itself wasn't the focus of the course we had on that, the [tag:functional-programming] paradigm was.

Comment: I wish the "technologies" field were more broad really. For those of us that aren't pure programmers (I'm UX) technologies is pretty limitng...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’ve expanded the size of that field, would you try again?

Comment: The new size is fine for my needs, thanks!